# Listbox not showing data in mvvm wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, listbox

Listbox not displaying data. Listbox is appearing but no data in it. This is to reuse listbox
for different forms. Could you help. This is just a listbox with some strings in it. I have
implemented it with mvvm pattern and wpf.

```
Mainwindow.xaml:

  <Window.DataContext>
    <local:Listboxviewmodel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ListBox Width="100" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Items,    
     Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,     
     Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
</Window>

mainwindow.xaml.cs:
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
 public MainWindow()
 {
     var model = new Listboxviewmodel();
     model.Items.Add("orange");
     model.Items.Add("apple");
     model.Items.Add("grapes");
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = new Listboxviewmodel();
     
     
 }
}
```

Listboxviewmodel is provided in the answer section.

---

listboxviewmodel.cs:

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
public class Listboxviewmodel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private ObservableCollection<string> _selectedItem;

    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            SetPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            SetPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void SetPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new    PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
   }


   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `DataContext` to the instance that you are adding items to:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var model = new Listboxviewmodel();
    model.Items.Add("orange");
    model.Items.Add("apple");
    model.Items.Add("grapes");
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = model; // <--
}
```

And there is no reason to set the `DataContext` in the XAML markup when you set it programmatically. Remove this:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:Listboxviewmodel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I dont have enough credits to upvote.

Comment: @mili Accepting the answer will show others that the question was answered

Answer (score 0):

this.DataContext = new Listboxviewmodel();

- The issue is here. You have populated a Listboxviewmodel named model , But while assigning DataContext , you are creating a new Listboxviewmodel.

Could you try assigning the model to the DataContext.